# Two indexes with same field in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

For example we have table:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_tbl` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `other_fields` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `id_type` (`id_type`),
 KEY `type_date` (`id_type`,`date`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Ther are two indexes: **id_type** and **id_type, date**.

As I know if we have index with two fields we kan use it as single index of first field.

Can I delete index **id_type** without losing in performance?

UPDATE: Asking this question cause noticed that sometime same field in different indexes has different cardinality.

Comment: yes, you can delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL 5.7.9 - Dropping **id_type** index doesnt make a difference. Multi column index(`type_date`) is applied for both queries.

**Explain queries output:**

```
mysql> explain SELECT id_type,date FROM my_tbl WHERE id_type='some';
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | my_tbl | NULL       | ref  | type_date     | type_date | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+-----



mysql> explain  SELECT id_type FROM my_tbl WHERE id_type='some';
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
        +----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | my_tbl | NULL       | ref  | type_date     | type_date | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
        +----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+---------


mysql> show indexes from my_tbl;
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| my_tbl |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| my_tbl |          1 | type_date |            1 | id_type     | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| my_tbl |          1 | type_date |            2 | date        | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+-------------
```

Comment: This is interesting. Can you try to run the same queries, adding the index of single column only as well and post the results?

Comment: @Starx: Same "type_date" index is applied even when both the single and multi column indexes are present

Answer (score 2):

`INDEX(a), INDEX(a, b)` -- Drop the former, since the latter can be used.

Having both wastes disk space and slows down inserts (a little).

`INDEX(a, c), INDEX(a, d)` -- You might find both of these to be useful.

`UNIQUE(a), INDEX(a, b)` -- Now, because of the uniqueness constraint, the former is required.  Drop the latter.

*On the other hand*...  `INDEX(a, b)` (in 2 of my examples) *could* be especially useful if it were a "covering" index.  That is, if the `SELECT` touched *both* `a` and `b` and *no* other columns.  In that case, the query is performed entirely in the index structure (BTree) and does not have to touch the Data structure.

[More info](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).